# Creating line in mean position respect to position of other lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line

I have a series of shapefiles (let's say 3 shape files), each of which contains a line representing the coastline during a certain period of prehistory.

- red line = coastline when sea level was -16 m than now
- green line = coastline when sea level was -14 m than now
- blue line = coastline when sea level was -5 m than now

[image: example]

The attributes table of the first shape file (which is referred to the moment in which sea level was 14 m lower than now) is made of 3 columns and 5369 rows and looks like this:

```
ID    GRIDCODE    Sea level
2247  0           -14
2244  0           -14
2245  0           -14
2241  0           -14
2243  0           -14
```

The attributes table of the second shape file (which is referred to the moment in which sea level was 5 m lower than now) is made of 3 columns and 6285 rows and looks like this:

```
ID    GRIDCODE    Sea level
1622  0           -5
1619  0           -5
1620  0           -5
1616  0           -5
1618  0           -5
```

The attributes table of the third shape file (which is referred to the moment in which sea level was 16 m lower than now) is made of 3 columns and 5382 rows and looks like this:

```
  ID    GRIDCODE    Sea level
  2352  0           -16
  2347  0           -16
  2348  0           -16
  2344  0           -16
  2345  0           -16
```

What I'd obtain is a new shapefile of a line representing the mean position of the coastline, calculated on the basis of the three initial shapefiles.

Comment: Does "mean" in this context mean "somewhere in the middle" or "considering the bathymetry/waterdepth"?

Comment: Considering the bathymetry/waterdepth.

Comment: Then you need current bathymetry data, I guess.

Comment: @Erik, thank you. I'm downloading tha bathymetry data I need, and I have to choose the format. The possibile options are the following: 2D netCDF (Grid and/or TID grid), GeoTIFF (Grid and/or TID grid), and Esri ASCII (Grid and/or TID grid). Can you please tell me which is the best?

Comment: Whichever you can work with, I guess.